# Concat MySQL Query

Tags: mysqli, concatenation

Here's my table:

```
item     groupID
-----------------------
foo      10
foo      11
foo      12
bar      1
bar      3
```

i need to run a query which results in this:

```
item     groupIDs
-----------------------
foo      10,11,12
bar      1,3
```

any ideas? 
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql - query group/concat question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568575/mysql-query-group-concat-question)

Answer (score 1):

ok i found out meanwhile :)

```
select item,group_concat(groupIDs) from mytable group by item
```